# Search a file based on a text file's words

Tags: windows, search

I want to search several words at the same time in a text file.

For example think I want to search these 3 words: Majid,superuser,device

Normally I should search for them one by one, and I can not search all of them at the same time. So I want to search these words at the same time in a text file.

I want to enter those 3 words in a text file, one word per line. Let's name it SearchText.
Now I have a Target Text which I want to search those words in it. Let's name it TargetText.

I want to tell an app or something similar to get words from SearchText and find them in TargetText and Highlights them or gives me the find result.

I hope I'm clear. So can anyone hep me?

Comment: For _all_ of the words, or for _any_ of the words?

Comment: Hi JdeBP, For all, I mean it searches for example for those 3 words (Majid,superuser,computer) and if it finds any of them, then it highlights them or give me the result.

Comment: "For all, I mean any." doesn't answer my question in a way that conveys what you want.  You really need to make it clear _what_ you want to match, and what you do not, before anyone can properly construct an answer to this question that not only says "Yes." but proceeds to explain how.  Edit the question to make it clear what you want.

Comment: What OS do you prefer? The answer will be different if it's windows or linux

Comment: Hi Nifle, I'm using windows.

Comment: Hi JdeBP, I have edited the post, If it is not clear again tell me please, and please don't vote for deleting it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep "Majid|superuser|device" filename.txt
```

On Windows you'll have to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm), [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or similar.

If the words must come from a file you could write a shell script to read that file and construct the argument to `grep`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows which suggests the native

```
findstr /C:"Majid superuser device" filename.txt
```

Comment: Hi RedGrittyBrick, But how to save the result? Is it possible to save find words in a text file?

Comment: Use redirection to save the results - append "`> savedresult.txt`" to the command

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. When on a Windows platform - Use Windows commands/tools.

I'd use **findstr** as follows:

> C:\some\directory>findstr "Majid superuser device" somefile

There is no need for **SearchText** to exist when searching for 3 keywords - but you could do this:

> C:\some\directory>notepad SearchText.

Enter your keywords separated by CRLF. Save file and do this:

> C:\some\directory>findstr /g:SearchText somefile